# Converting datetime not converting datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

So I have a table and I am trying to convert the time from its current format that looks like this

```
Sep 17 2020  1:07AM
```

to

```
2020-09-16 20:07:00.000
```

if I try to update the entire table by

```
UPDATE
OOTYPE 
SET
OOTYPE.LastModified = CONVERT(DATETIME, SWITCHOFFSET(CONVERT(DATETIMEOFFSET, LastModified), 
DATENAME(TzOffset, SYSDATETIMEOFFSET())))
```

it runs successfully but the times are still in the format

```
Sep 17 2020  1:07AM
```

However, if I just run a simple select statement to show it changed

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, SWITCHOFFSET(CONVERT(DATETIMEOFFSET,lastmodified), DATENAME(TzOffset, SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()))) FROM [OOTYPE]
```

The output is exactly what I'm looking for.....

```
2020-09-16 20:07:00.000
```

Anyone have any idea where I'm screwing this simple change up at, I have put an embarrassing amount of time into this....

Comment: What is the datatype of column `LastModified`?

Comment: varchar(26) good sir

Comment: Store `datetime` as that; then use `CONVERT` for the formatted display - it is much easier to store dates as dates!

Comment: Not really an option for me, I'm pulling the table from a linked server that I have no control over and it copies the exact information unfortunately and needs to stay as varchar

Comment: The problem is you're storing date and time values as a `varchar`; there are 6 date and time data types and all are infinitely better suited for the storage of such data. As for the format, date and time data is stored as a binary value, it the application/presentation layer that should be worrying about the format not the RDBMS. Fix the design and then make the formatting happen in your application.

Comment: I Also tried converting the LastModified column to the datatype DATETIME and i am still having the same issue

Comment: You can create a _view_ that includes the column as a suitable date/time data type. As others have noted, formatting the value for display is best left to the application, not done in the database.

Comment: You haven't stated why you want to do this.  What is the end game?  If you are able to convert the data from one format to the other, that won't prevent whatever is feeding this table from entering more values in the unwanted format.  If your outcome is a report or a display, you probably want to use a view.  But you have also not told us what the data types are.  `Sep 17 2020  1:07AM` will fit in a varchar(19).  `2020-09-16 17:07:00.000` will not.  You say "it runs successfully", but it doesn't.  If it did, the values would change.  What messages do you get?

Comment: Really what i am asking is why CONVERT(DATETIME, SWITCHOFFSET(CONVERT(DATETIMEOFFSET, lastmodified), DATENAME(TzOffset, SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()))) is converting the time to the readable format instead of like 2020-09-16 20:07:00.000.

Comment: It isn't, but if you view the data, your viewing client makes some assumptions and finds a way to display it to you. If you've converted it (or stored it) as a date/datetime datetype then its stored as a pure date with no formatting.

Comment: Good point, Dale K.  Samuel:  Are you sure it's varchar(something), not a date/time type?  Maybe it's already the correct data type and your computer settings are defining how you see it.  Try this: `select s.name as 'Schema', o.name as 'Table', c.name as 'Column', t.name as 'Type', c.length, c.scale, c.prec from sys.sysobjects o  inner join sys.syscolumns c on c.id = o.id  inner join sys.schemas s on s.schema_id = o.uid  inner join sys.systypes t on t.xtype = c.xtype where o.name = 'OOTYPE'  and c.name = 'lastmodified'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I follow you correctly:

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar, CONVERT(datetime, 'Sep 17 2020  1:07AM'), 121)
```

You should use convert style `121` which is `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss.mmm`.